# SecurityException in google play services?

Tags: google-play-services, android-securityexception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.my.package.name'.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzv$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj$zzc.zzvA(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj$zzf.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacv.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Seeing a securityException in google play services most recently. This crash is happening in Android 4.4, 5.0, 6.0.

Anyone had faced this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

[`SecurityException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityException.html) was usually thrown by the security manager to indicate a security violation. If the [Google Play services client library](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview) version is greater than 8.1, the app throws a security exception if a required runtime permission is missing from AndroidManifest.xml. You may check on this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/26) if it helps.

Similar [issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/xox8L1H-4oQ) was also posted. You can file in this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?vid=0-100019039405-1483961520621#topic=3450769) if you think this is a bug so the Engineers can look into it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your initial thoughts.

First of all, we are not 100% sure where exactly this crash is happening. Stack trace just tells the google play services package names.

This issue has started appearing after we switched to latest google play services 10.0.1 and latest support library version 25.1.0. So thinking of downgrading these libraries to the previous versions to see if it helps.

I am not sure that this could happen because of runtime permission model since the same crash is happening in previous android versions.

Maybe google play services team know this better.